# Creating tables at bookmarks in a Word document through Excel VBA from dynamic controls

Tags: excel, ms-word, bookmarks, vba

I'm hoping someone can help me on this as I have been banging my head against this for about a week or so.

I have a userform that creates a set of controls (3 text boxes and a combo box) and interates a counter by 1 each time the button is pressed.

I have written an Excel VBA Macro that should open up a specific document (which will be a dotx in the final version but is a docx for this test) and;

Go to a set bookmark in the Word Document ("table1")
Move to the start of the line with the bookmark
Move up to the previous line
Create a table with 1 row and 3 columns.
Inserts the values from the first and second textboxes and combobox into columns 1,2 and 3 respectively
Return to the specified "table2" bookmark and repeat this for each iterated line of the dynamically created controls

Also the Macro should

Go to a set bookmark in the Word Document ("table2")
Move to the start of the line with the bookmark
Move up to the previous line
Create a table with 1 row and 2 columns.
Inserts the values from the first and third textbox into columns 1 and 2 respectively
Return to the specified "table2" bookmark and repeat this for each iterated line of the dynamically created controls

So basically at each bookmark if there are 3 lines of dynamic controls after the macro runs there should be

A table with 3 rows and 3 columns located above bookmark "table1" containing the values from the first and second textbox and the combobox value.
A table with 3 rows and 2 columns located above bookmark "table2" containing the values from the first and third textbox values.

So my problem is that when the macro is run it either creates one line of the table at the top of the document, another at the "table1" bookmark and one at the "table2" bookmark or the 3 column table is created then another 3 column table is created inside the first cell of the first table and so on.

I am convinced I am missing something in regards to cursor control (as the usual problem is the first table cell is created at the first line of the document then the cursor seems to move to the "table1" bookmark and the macro continues from there).

If someone could give me some pointers on this I would greatly appreciated as I feel I am almost there but that I'm just overlooking something.

Here is the code I have so far, apologies in advance for any unused variables this is back of a napkin coding.

```
Private Sub CommandButton14_Click() 'Create WO Letter
'Open WO letter and copy paste data

    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document

    Dim riskCombo As Control
    Dim theTextBox802 As Control
    Dim theTextBox803 As Control
    Dim theTextBox804 As Control
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim c As Integer

Dim intNoOfColumns

Dim wdDoc

Dim objRange1

Dim objRange2

Dim objTable1

Dim objTable2

    b = iRiskCount
    c = 1


    If Me.WOLetter1.Value = False And Me.WOLetter2.Value = False And Me.WOLetter3.Value = False And Me.WOLetter4.Value = False Then
        MsgBox "You Must Choose a Letter Type"
    Exit Sub

    End If

    If UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Frame15.Controls("Risk" & c).Value = "Risk" Then
         MsgBox "Select Risk Level for line " & c
    Exit Sub

    End If

        If Me.WOLetter1.Value = True Then
                Set objWord = New Word.Application
                objWord.DisplayAlerts = False
                objWord.Visible = True
                objWord.Activate
                Set wdDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\WOTest.docx")


        ElseIf Me.WOLetter2.Value = True Then
                Set objWord = New Word.Application
                objWord.DisplayAlerts = False
                objWord.Visible = True
                'objWord.Documents.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\WOTest.docx", ReadOnly:=True '"\test.dotx", ReadOnly:=True'"\Doc.dotm", ReadOnly:=True '"\test.dotx", ReadOnly:=True
                objWord.Activate

        ElseIf Me.WOLetter3.Value = True Then
                Set objWord = New Word.Application
                objWord.DisplayAlerts = False
                objWord.Visible = True
                'objWord.Documents.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\WOTest.docx", ReadOnly:=True '"\test.dotx", ReadOnly:=True'"\Doc.dotm", ReadOnly:=True '"\test.dotx", ReadOnly:=True
                objWord.Activate

        ElseIf Me.WOLetter4.Value = True Then
                Set objWord = New Word.Application
                objWord.DisplayAlerts = False
                objWord.Visible = True
                'objWord.Documents.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\WOTest.docx", ReadOnly:=True '"\test.dotx", ReadOnly:=True'"\Doc.dotm", ReadOnly:=True '"\test.dotx", ReadOnly:=True
                objWord.Activate

        End If



        For Each riskCombo In UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Frame15.Controls

            If b > 0 Then

            Set objRange1 = objWord.Selection.Range
            Set objRange2 = objWord.Selection.Range

    'Table1
            objWord.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="table1"
            objWord.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdMove
            objWord.Selection.MoveUp     

            wdDoc.Tables.Add objRange1, 1, 3
                objWord.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="table1"
                objWord.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdMove
            objWord.Selection.MoveUp
            Set objTable1 = wdDoc.Tables(1)

    'Table 2

            objWord.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="table2"
            objWord.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdMove
            objWord.Selection.MoveUp

            wdDoc.Tables.Add objRange2, 1, 2
                objWord.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="table2"
                objWord.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdMove
            objWord.Selection.MoveUp
            Set objTable2 = wdDoc.Tables(1)

            With objTable1
                .Cell(0, 1).Range.Text = UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Frame15.Controls("Text5" & c).Value
                .Cell(0, 2).Range.Text = UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Frame15.Controls("Text6" & c).Value
                .Cell(0, 3).Range.Text = UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Frame15.Controls("Risk" & c).Value
            End With

            With objTable2
                .Cell(0, 1).Range.Text = UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Frame15.Controls("Text5" & c).Value
                .Cell(0, 2).Range.Text = UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Frame15.Controls("Text7" & c).Value
            End With


                    c = c + 1
                    b = b - 1

        End If

    Next riskCombo

            objTable1.Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=30, RulerStyle:= _
            wdAdjustNone

            objTable1.Columns(2).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=350, RulerStyle:= _
            wdAdjustNone

            objTable1.Columns(3).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=75, RulerStyle:= _
            wdAdjustNone

            objTable2.Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=30, RulerStyle:= _
            wdAdjustNone

            objTable2.Columns(2).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=425, RulerStyle:= _
            wdAdjustNone


End Sub 'end of test
```

Even some reassurance that I am on the right track with this would be appreciated as I have been beating my head against this for the past week.

Comment: You are setting both table one and table two to be the same. Should they be different? 
**"Set objTable1 = wdDoc.Tables(1)"**
**"Set objTable2 = wdDoc.Tables(1)"**

Comment: Yes you're right that was an oversight on my part. Apologies

Comment: Was that the answer?

Comment: Yes it was. I had to set up both tables separately so instead of them both being in the same For Each loop I put them into separate loops.

Comment: Ok, I made that an answer below. You can mark it to close this question.

Comment: Thanks HackSlash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting both table one and table two to be the same.

```
"Set objTable1 = wdDoc.Tables(1)" 
"Set objTable2 = wdDoc.Tables(1)"
```